# Select from DB all records or by array if present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In RoR app I want to write a model method that will return some records.
It should select by ids if ids are present or all records if not

```
def viewing_duration(ids = nil)
  if ids
    tracks.where(video_id: ids).sum('age(updated_at, created_at)')
  else
    tracks.sum('age(updated_at, created_at)')
  end
end
```

Question:
How I can write query in one line and pass the expression right to `where` method?
Something like this:

```
tracks.where(video_id: ids.nil? ? 'all' : ids).sum('age(updated_at, created_at)')
```

Comment: Why do you need one line?

Comment: I don't like if-else-end blocks :) and there were code repetitions, which is bad. But Siim suggests a good idea of how to remove repetition, so I will keep if-else-end block.

Comment: One-liners are generally much harder to understand than normal if-else blocks IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping it as more lines probably makes it easier to understand. I suggest keeping it close to as it is while removing repetition:

```ruby
def viewing_duration(ids = nil)
  if ids
    tracks.where(video_id: ids)
  else
    tracks
  end.sum('age(updated_at, created_at)')
end
```

If you do want to pass something into where to find all records, you can use an sql statement that will always evaluate to true. For example:

```ruby
tracks.where(ids.nil? ? '1=1' : { video_id: ids }).sum('age(updated_at, created_at)')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not one line, but as idea how to organize your code using chaining

```
def viewing_duration(ids = nil)
  entities = tracks
  entities = entities.where(video_id: ids) if ids
  entities.sum('age(updated_at, created_at)')
end
```